# Extract value of parameter at specific time step

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am modelling the temperature changes in a building and want to extract the indoor temperature at a specific time (3 hrs) for a 24 hr simulation. However I can't find a way to do this within Simulink.

I have tried the scope, time scope and display nodes but none will allow me to set a time for evaluation. Outputting the data into Matlab gives me a time series which I suppose I could manipulate to extract the information but there must be a simple way of doing this within Simulink as the data is all there. Is there some node I am missing?

Comment: It is easiest to use a `To Workspace` block, set that to Timeseries, and find the index you are interested in using e.g. `idx = find(temperature.Time, 1, 'first');` and then obtain the temp `temp_3hr = temperature.Data(idx);`. You can set the sample time for the `To Workspace` block to 1 hr, to limit the data you are putting in your workspace, but you cannot specify only one time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the "[Cursor Measurements Panel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/cursor-measurements-panel.html)".
From the menu bar, select **Tools » Measurement » Cursor Measurements** to open it.

[image]

Here you can enter any x-axis value for which you want to find corresponding y-axis value.

[image]